# Which test to use with this 2 x 2 contingency table?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Which text could be appropriate for this 2 x 2 table: the occurence of 2 species at an archaeological site

```
 inside burial      the entire site not including the burial
```

dom
mac

10 : 29

1  : 13

I would like to test whether *dom* had preferntial access into the burial as compared to *mac*, since more specimens of the former occur in the burial than of the latter.
Whether assumptions of indipendence between the 2 samples hold and the type of distribution of such data are not known.

Much appreciated
Lior

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all samples are independent, fishers exact test should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Kirsten!

Comment: Probably, I have no good way of determining independence between the 2 samples and among the observations, I can only assume the mice individually entered the burial context over a period of time for the shelter it provided and died there.

Comment: wikipedia provide a very nice explanation of fishers exact test. Try to read part of it. There are multiple other webpages that describe it well, together with the independent assumptions, there is not point for me to repeat these explanations here. The independence in my comment is not something you test, but something you assume.